# analytic implies power series, is this proof good enough

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

If $f$ is analytic on some ball, say $B_R(a)$, then
$$f(z)=\sum a_n(z-a)^n$$
for $z \in B_R(a)$, is convergent where
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)$$
are the coefficients.

Let $0<r<R$ be such that
$$\overline{B_r(a)} \subset B_R(a).$$
If we let $\gamma = a+re^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2 \pi]$, then by previous proposition, we have that
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw.$$
Where $z \in B_r(a)$, $\vert w - a \vert = r$.
Note that we can write
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{w-z}&=\frac{1}{w-a+a-z}\\
    &= \frac{1}{(w-a)(1-\frac{z-a}{w-a})}\\
    &=\frac{1}{w-a} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{z-a}{w-a})^n
\end{align*}
Thus we can write
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}} f(w) dw.$$
Define
$$g_n(w):=\frac{(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}} f(w).$$
And since the trace of $\gamma$ is compact, we can define a max via
$$M:= \max\{\vert f(w) \vert : w \in \gamma([0,2 \pi])\},$$
then we have that
\begin{align*}
    \vert g_n(w) \vert &= \bigg\vert \frac{(z-a)^nf(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} \bigg\vert \\
    &\le \frac{\vert z - a \vert^n}{\vert w - a \vert^{n+1}} \cdot M\\
    &=\frac{\vert z - a \vert^n}{r^{n+1}} \cdot M\\
    &=\bigg(\frac{\vert z - a \vert}{r}\bigg)^n \cdot \frac{M}{r}
\end{align*}
Defining
$$M_n:=\bigg(\frac{\vert z - a \vert}{r}\bigg)^n \cdot \frac{M}{r},$$
we note that $\sum M_n$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since $\frac{\vert z - a \vert}{r}<1$. Thus by the Weierstrass M-test,  the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^k g_n(w)=\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f(w)(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}} \rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f(w)(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}}$$
uniformly. We can then write
\begin{align*}
    f(z) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f(w)(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}}dw\\
    &=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_\gamma \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f(w)(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}}dw\\
    &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^k \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}} dw\\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{(z-a)^n}{2 \pi i}\bigg) \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} dw \\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} dw\bigg) (z-a)^n
\end{align*}
Where we have that
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}:=a_n \space \text{by Corollary of Cauchys Theorem}$$
as needed for the coefficients. As the statement does not depend on $r$, this holds for all $z \in B_R(a)$, as needed. I basically tried giving detail to the proof given in Conway. TO better understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is perfect, just a little detail. When you give the parametrization of $B_r(a) $ is $\gamma(t) =a+re^{it}$ instead of  $\gamma(t) =a+e^{it}$ as you wrote

Comment: oh you're right lol